# How to convert rpath for windows?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, visual-studio, gcc, fedora

I want to convert this rpath written in Fedora using matlab to windows. It should be compatible in windows.How to change the gcc compiler which will be compatible for windows ? Here is the code

```
 mex -v CC="gcc" CFLAGS="\$CFLAGS" LDFLAGS="\$LDFLAGS -Wl','-rpath','C:\OpenSim 3.2\bin\lib" ...
    -I/home/mammoth/e/lehre/FrameWorks/MotorControlFramework/Simulator/simtk/opensimbin/sdk/include ...
    -I/home/mammoth/e/lehre/FrameWorks/MotorControlFramework/Simulator/simtk/opensimbin/sdk/include/SimTK/include ...
    -L/home/mammoth/e/lehre/FrameWorks/MotorControlFramework/Simulator/simtk/opensimbin/lib ...
    -losimSimulation -losimCommon -losimActuators -losimTools -losimAnalyses -lSimTKcommon -lSimTKsimbody -lSimTKmath -lSimTKlapack ...
    simOsimModelLinearController.cpp
```

Comment: Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx) out. I'm not sure this is possible for _WIN_ (maybe - I'm not sure, I could be talking nonsense here -  unless you build your dlls as assemblies and at link time their path is included from the manifest into the executable, and at runtime the dlls are loaded from that location?).

Comment: I dont know man, its not working

Comment: That was kind of my point. I don't think it's possible in native _WIN_ (you could use an intermediator, e.g.: [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com)).